# togglebutton.isChecked() is not working?

Tags: java, android, togglebutton

I am working with an Arduino and trying use two toggle buttons to connect and enable the Arduino. I don't want to be able to press the enable button until I have connected the robot. Here is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Arduino arduino = null;
ToggleButton enable, connect;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ToggleButton connect = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonConnect);
    ToggleButton enable = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonEnable);

}

public void onToggleClicked(View view) {


    switch(view.getId()) {

        case R.id.buttonConnect:

            boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

            if(on){

                //Take the text from editText1 and make it the IP Address
                EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                String ip = text.getText().toString();
                arduino = new Arduino(ip);

                arduino.connect();

                arduino.disable();

            } else {

                arduino.disable();
                arduino.disconnect();
                enable.setChecked(false);
            }
        break;  



        case R.id.buttonEnable:

            boolean click = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

            if(click && connect.isChecked()) {

                arduino.enable();

            }else {

                System.out.println("Not Connected");
                enable.setChecked(False);
                arduino.disable();
            }
        break;  

        default:

        break;  

        }

    }
```

I know the program is not reaching the `else` statement in the buttonEnable case because it is not printing out "Not Connected." I have also tried to use `connect.isEnabled()`in my if statement but that doesn't work either. Does anybody have answer? Thank you!

Comment: What is actually calling your `onToggleClicked` method?

Comment: I thought the method was called whenever a toggle button was clicked? Do I need an onClickListener?

Comment: Yes. You need some way to tell the `ToggleButton` which method needs to be called. `ToggleButton` extends `Button` so try a standard `View.OnClickListener`.

Comment: Actually you could also try `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` as `ToggleButton` extends `CompoundButton` directly (and `Button` indirectly. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

Comment: Ahh, I figured it out. I don't necessarily need an onClickListener. I forgot `android:onClick="onToggleClicked"` in my xml. Thank you though, if you would not have posted the link I would have never have found it! @Squonk

Answer (score 0):

Try to set on click listener to attach the code execution to you button